# How to convert columns data in comma separated list

Tags: sql, advantage-database-server

I am in little strange situation. It is a third party application which from front end doesn't allow user procedures or udf/scalar functions to be called.

Only option is to write SQL and below is how my data looks. ***First pic has a mistake last PID was suppose to be 1 and second last 2.***

[image]

What I need it to be is this,

[image]

This can be easily done using UDF/cursor in this Advantage Database Server 9 but I don't have a choice. I don't know if it is really possible. In Sybase there exist a function called list which does this sort of work very easily but not sure here.

Application does allow to call built in functions.

Comment: does it have something like GROUP_CONCAT?

Comment: Not that I know off but I am searching in documentation

Comment: if not, please read this discussion. It may help you implementing an equivalent. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic984025-391-1.aspx

Comment: The GROUP_CONCAT is not currently supported but it is being worked on. If you are using ADS 9 or later, and the third party application uses data dictionary as backend database (look for *.add in connection path), then you should be able to write a User Defined Function to return this. A UDF is called as part of a normal SQL statement. so if you are allowed to execute your own SQL, you should be able to define and use the UDF without problem.

Comment: I will try to write it today but I want to make sure I close cursor correctly. I will post the code little later in the day, can you be kind enough to confirm I am closing the cursor correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating following function by connecting to Data Dictionary but I got the error.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetReport_Meds
   ( 
   PID varchar(15)
   )
   RETURNS String
BEGIN
DECLARE Meds String;
DECLARE CurMeds cursor AS SELECT  med_code from medication where patient = 
TRIM(PID) and end_date is null;
Meds = "";
OPEN CurMeds;
WHILE FETCH CurMeds DO
Meds = TRIM(Meds)+TRIM(CurMeds.med_code)+",";
END WHILE;
CLOSE CurMeds;
RETURN LEFT(Meds,LEN(Meds)-1);
END;
```

```
 poQuery: Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = HY000;   NativeError = 5054;
  [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL][ASA] Error 5054:  The command cannot
 be completed with the current user permissions.  Cannot 
create function object in the data dictionary.
```

I have requested the company who created this db/app to add this function in the db so I can use it, lets see where I land.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @table table
(
   PID integer,
   Medicine varchar(10)  )

insert into @table values (1, 'ABC')
insert into @table values (2, 'ABC')
insert into @table values (1, 'DEF')
insert into @table values (2, 'DEF')
insert into @table values (1, 'GHI')



SELECT DISTINCT a.PID,
                Medicine = STUFF((SELECT ',' + b.Medicine
                                    FROM @table b
                                    WHERE a.PID = b.PID
                                      FOR XML Path('')),1,1,'')
FROM @table a
```

**RESULT:**

```
**PID   Medicine**
1   ABC,DEF,GHI
2   ABC,DEF
```

Comment: STUFF is not a support feature in Advantage.

Comment: All STUFF is doing is removing the first `,` character in the return string from the XML Path query. You can remove it in a number of ways but STUFF is easiest since don't need to know length of string.