# How can we get a column values as comma separated in Advantage Database server?

Tags: sql, advantage-database-server

Below statements fails for ADS

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' ,'') + Name FROM Product
SELECT @listStr
```

Please help

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375218/how-to-convert-columns-data-in-comma-separated-list

Answer (score 1):

In general, the preferred way to do this is to use whatever function the dbms provides. MySQL has group_concat(), PostgreSQL has array_agg(), Oracle has listagg(), etc. But Advantage Server doesn't seem to support any functions like these.

The next best way is to build a user-defined function. [Advantage supports user-defined functions](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11/index.html). [Here's one implementation](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/forum/questions/700/how-to-concatenate-values-in-a-column); I haven't tested it.

Other ways, which might or might not be possible, are

- extending the dbms by writing custom functions in a low-level language, often C or C++, and
- doing the concatenation in application code instead of on the server.

Comment: Hello Mike, Thanks for reply. But implementation link you have provided is same as user defined functions. Please get me that if possible.

Comment: @DileepPaul: Corrected the link. Sorry about that.